# How to redirect all requests except for one path in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have some one path I want to keep on a server, but I want to redirect all other requests to another domain. How do I successfully serve all requests at a given location, but every other request redirect to example.com?

```
server {
   root /var/www/my_example/html;
   index index.html;
  
   location /path/to/keep/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
   }

   # everywhere else redirect requests to domain.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern seems to work, although I could get more creative with regex.

```
location / {
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://example.com$request_uri permanent;
}

location /path/to/keep/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
}
```

I think it works because of how Nginx handles precedence.